# merge function and namespaces over multiple files

Tags: typescript, module, namespaces

## How to Merge Function and Namespaces over multiple files?

### File Structure

```
module/
├── module.a.ts
├── module.b.ts
├── module.c.ts
├── module.barrel.ts
└── index.ts
```

#### the `module.a.ts` or `module.b.ts` or `module.c.ts` are submodule.

inside each submodule we have a function to invoke `console.log('from {MODULE_NAME}')`

something like :

```js
export function a(){
  console.log('from A');
}
```

#### re-export as **barrel** inside `module.barrel.ts` file

for example :

```js
export * from './mdoule.a.ts';
export * from './module.b.ts';
export * from './module.c.ts';
```

#### re-export from barrel as grouped namespace inside `index.ts`

alike below :

```js
export * as MyModule from './module.barrel';
```

#### Usage

Then, We can import named `MyModule` from `./module` or `./module/index` file, and call all of barreled exports :

```js
import { MyModule } from './module'

MyModule.a();
MyModule.b();
MyModule.c();
```

### Question

How can merge MyModule as function?

for example use something like :

```js
export function MyModule(){
  console.log('from ROOT MODULE');
}
```

and using it by :

```js
import { MyModule } from './module';

MyModule(); // also call `my-module` as function
MyModule.a();
MyModule.b();
MyModule.c();
```